# count the number of values greater than each value in a column of an array in r

Tags: arrays, r

Say I had an array with x representing repeat measurements (1-4), y representing treatments (A,B) and z representing timepoints (1-3)

```
x <- c(2,2,4,15,17,13,3,10,3,4,11,14,1,3,19,6,13,6,12,18,9,13,12,16)
dim(x) <- c(4,2,3)

, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   17
[2,]    2   13
[3,]    4    3
[4,]   15   10

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    1
[2,]    4    3
[3,]   11   19
[4,]   14    6

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   13    9
[2,]    6   13
[3,]   12   12
[4,]   18   16
```

I want to create a new array that has the number of times each replicate is greater than all other replicates for that treatment and timepoint combination:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    0 #both 4 and 15 are bigger then 2, so for 1,1,1 the result is 2
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    1    3 #15 is the only replicate bigger than 4 so result for 3,1,1 is 1
[4,]    0    2

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    1    0
[4,]    0    1

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3 
[2,]    3    1 
[3,]    2    2 
[4,]    0    0
```

Comment: Could we get the used code to produce the original array?

Comment: Don't you have the counts backward (or the question framed backward)? e.g. for c(2,2,4,15) 2 is greater than 0 of the other replicates. Shouldn't the array vector [1,1,1] == c(0,0,2,3) not c(2,2,1,0)? Or am I misreading this?

Comment: I just made up this array for simplicity. The data I want to apply this on has 2 factors of 50 levels each and 10,000 replicates [1:10000, 1:50, 1:50]. Separately for each combination of factor levels, I take the first replicate and see how many of the other replicates are larger, then the second replicate and see how many of the other replicates are larger and so on until I have an array with the number of other replicates that are larger for each of the original replicates (separately for each combination of the factor levels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` can do this, acting within each column (2) and strata (3):

```
## recreate your data array:
arr <- c(2,2,4,15,17,13,3,10,3,4,11,14,1,3,19,6,13,6,12,18,9,13,12,16)
dim(arr) <- c(4,2,3)

## one liner using apply
apply(arr, 2:3, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) sum(y < x) ) )

#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    0
#[2,]    2    1
#[3,]    1    3
#[4,]    0    2
#
#, , 2
# 
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    3
#[2,]    2    2
#[3,]    1    0
#[4,]    0    1
# 
#, , 3
# 
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    3    1
#[3,]    2    2
#[4,]    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... If you're question is incorrectly phrased (as I suspect above), then you will need to use "<" instead of ">".

```
a <- array(rnorm(24), dim= c(4,2,3))

cnts <- function(a) {
  a2 <- array(NA, dim= dim(a))
  for (i in 1:dim(a)[3]) {
    for (j in 1:dim(a)[2]) {
      for (k in 1:length(a[,j,i])) {
        a2[k,j,i] <- sum(a[k,j,i] > a[,j,i])
      }
    }
  }
  return(a2)
}
```